# Using shapely with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, gis, psycopg2, shapely

Are there "best practices" of using shapely with PostgreSQL?

Playing around with [register_adapter](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter) and friends I have the following code. Are there any better ways?

```
from psycopg2.extensions import (
    adapt, register_adapter, AsIs, new_type, register_type
)
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import numpy as np
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', user='postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE pts (pt POINT)')
conn.commit()


def quote(v):
    return adapt(v).getquoted().decode()


def adapt_point(pt):
    x, y = quote(pt.x), quote(pt.y)
    return AsIs("'(%s, %s)'" % (x, y))

register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)


points = [
    (Point(x, y), )
    for x, y in
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (0, 1)]
]
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO pts (pt) VALUES (%s)', points)
conn.commit()


def adapt_polygon(poly):
    pts = np.stack(poly.exterior.xy).T
    inner = ', '.join('(%s, %s)' % (quote(x), quote(y)) for x, y in pts)
    return AsIs("'(%s)'" % inner)

register_adapter(Polygon, adapt_polygon)


def cast_point(value, cur):
    if value is None:
        return None
    # '(2.7,3.6)'
    try:
        x, y = value[1:-1].split(',')
    except ValueError:
        raise psycopg2.InterfaceError('bad point representation: %r' % value)

    return Point(float(x), float(y))

cur.execute('SELECT NULL::point')
point_oid = cur.description[0].type_code
POINT = new_type((point_oid,), 'POINT', cast_point)
register_type(POINT)

poly = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
cur.execute('''
    SELECT pt
    FROM pts
    WHERE
        pt <@ polygon %s
    ''', (poly,))

for pt, in cur:
    print(pt, type(pt))
```

Comment: You can directly insert and extract WKT and WKB into PostGIS. You can likewise use Shapely's wkt and wkb modules with the accompanying loads and dumps methods to transfer your geometry back and forth.

Comment: Using Shapely, you should use WKT and WKB representations directly.
If you are using *register_adapter* and want to do it by hand, than, no need to install Shapely (which is a bit heavy and has dependencies), you directly use the very thin geometrical objects from *pygeoif*